# Can I use the Coinbase Oauth flow to allow the user to make a payment?

Tags: ruby, api, oauth, coinbase-api

I'm using Ruby with the Coinbase 2 API.  I'm confused about when I need to use the Coinbase OAuth flow.  What I would like to do is have the user donate to our site.  Is this something that the OAuth flow can be used for?  If so, what would the series of calls taht would need to be made between myt site and Coinbase to make this donation possible?

This question specifically deals with Coinbase and its API.  I'm not interested in answers that don't directly address taht.

Comment: The OAuth flow can be used for this, but if you just need to to accept donations you can just use https://commerce.coinbase.com/signin